# How to convert an environment into a comment, except for a given command?

Tags: comments

The comment package allows one to set up a given environment (let us call it `toto`) to become a comment and have its contents disappear. How could I do this but still have a single command (let us call it `\keepthis{...}` inside it being executed? For example

```
\begin{toto}
Stuff which will disappear...
\keepthis{Something which must appear nevertheless}
Again stuff which will disappear...
\end{toto}
```

In other words, how can we have a `comment`-like environment which kills all text, math, commands, except for a single command and its arguments? This would mean that `comment` searches not only for `\end{toto}` but also for `\keepthis{...}` which it executes by restoring all `\catcode`s and the like, and then again searches for both until it finds an `\end{toto}` which really restores everything. Is that possible?

Comment: Good question, but can you expand this into an MWE? :-)

Comment: Why don't you want to use
`\begin{toto}
Stuff which will disappear...
\end{toto}
Something which must appear nevertheless
\begin{toto}
Again stuff which will disappear...
\end{toto}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `l3regex` to extract the proper token lists.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,environ,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{toto}
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \g_yannis_toto_show_bool
   { \BODY }
   { \par \yannis_toto_keep:V \BODY }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\showtoto}{}
 {
  \bool_gset_true:N \g_yannis_toto_show_bool
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\hidetoto}{}
 {
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_yannis_toto_show_bool
 }

\bool_new:N \g_yannis_toto_show_bool
\seq_new:N \l__yannis_toto_keep_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \yannis_toto_keep:n
 {
  \regex_extract_all:nnN { \c{keepthis}\s*\cB..*?\cE. } { #1 } \l__yannis_toto_keep_seq
  \seq_use:Nn \l__yannis_toto_keep_seq { \par }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \yannis_toto_keep:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\keepthis}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\hidetoto

\section{One instance}

Here is a toto environment

\begin{toto}
Stuff which will disappear...
\keepthis{Something which must appear nevertheless}
Again stuff which will disappear...
\end{toto}

\section{Two instances}
Here is a toto environment

\begin{toto}
Stuff which will disappear...
\keepthis{Something which must appear nevertheless}
Again stuff which will disappear...
\keepthis{Something which must appear nevertheless}
Again stuff which will disappear...
\end{toto}

\showtoto

\section{One instance}
Here is a toto environment

\begin{toto}
Stuff which will disappear...
\keepthis{Something which must appear nevertheless}
Again stuff which will disappear...
\end{toto}

\section{Two instances}
Here is a toto environment

\begin{toto}
Stuff which will disappear...
\keepthis{Something which must appear nevertheless}
Again stuff which will disappear...
\keepthis{Something which must appear nevertheless}
Again stuff which will disappear...
\end{toto}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This sounds really great, I never imagined LaTeX could one day do that. Now I have to try whether it is robust. And since this is part of LaTeX3, are there any prerequisites in terms of packages? or incompatibilities with other popular packages?

Comment: @yannis You just need an up-to-date TeX distribution